# Saving an array to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, nsurl

How is an array saved to NSUserDefaults?

I have the following code which tries to store an array of NSURLs

```
NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[mySingleton sharedMySingleton].sharedURLS];
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defs setObject:temp forKey:@"URLs"];
```

but I get a warning

> -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value

What is the correct way to store this or  collection of NSURLS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't directly store an `NSURL` in `NSUserDefaults`, only `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`; also, any `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` may only contain objects of these types. You'll have to convert the NSURLs into one of these types, most likely by using absoluteString to convert them into NSStrings.

Comment: Great, thanks. So if I store the list of NSString representations, how would I get the url after reading in the strings so that I can use the url to access the Asset.

Comment: `[NSURL URLWithString:string]`

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to create an ALAsset from a url? If I do this NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlStrings objectAtIndex:i]];
  ALAsset *tAsset = [[ALAsset alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; I get a crash due to unrecognized selector sent to initWithContentsOfURL

Comment: See `ALAssetsLibrary`, particularly `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:`.

Comment: @Helium3 would you mind checking my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670025/image-url-saving

Comment: @Anomie would you mind checking my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670025/image-url-saving

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides with `[mySingleton sharedMySingleton].sharedURLS`. NSURls can't be stored in NSUserDefaults, at least in the NSURL class, as they aren't property list objects (explanation below). I would recommend converting the URLs to NSStrings and then placing them in NSUserDefaults, like so:

`NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];`

There's a similar problem another user had here ( [NSUserDefaults won't save NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144860/nsuserdefaults-wont-save-nsdictionary)), where the issue was that the objects that the programmer put into the NSDictionary (in this case, NSArray), weren't property list objects. Basically, property lists objects are things like NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray or NSDictionary, the required format for saving to NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if you want save Object Like Array ,So you use Archived Class

    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[mySingleton sharedMySingleton].sharedURLS];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:temp] forKey:@"URLs"];

you also need coder and decoder method for this.  
    This is Working Fine For Me.
```