# Image URL saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Here is how my project works, I have a `UIScrollView` below it is a button `addButton`, when clicked redirects you to the `AGImagePickerController` (For those who doesn't know AGImagePickerController,it is a multiple image picker). Then you clicked the images(single or multiple images). When you press `DONE`, it will save the images in `NSCachesDirectory`. It will show the image chosen in `UIScrollView` (Which can be deleted). When you pressed the `addButton` again, it will show you the image `picked` a while ago with a `checkMark`.

**PROBLEM :** When I delete the image in the `UIScrollView` the image that was deleted in the `AGimagePickerController` is still `checked`. Needed is when deleted in the `UIScrollVIew` will also be remove in the `AGimagePickerController`.

What I wanted to do is, save its image by its `URL` then put it in a folder inside my `NSCachesDirectory` so I can load it easily, but I dont know where to start, since Im arranging my images in the `UIScrollView` by names with integers. Hope someone could suggest what to do. Thankyou Very Much.

**NOTE :** To those who have read this, please comment on what part of the code you want me to post here, or the part on which your having a problem with. Thankyou again.

---

**CODE:**

Here is my `DONE` part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {

    //NSLog(@"%@", [info objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%u.png", i]];

    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];

    //----resize the images
    image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:image toSize:CGSizeMake(256,256*image.size.height/image.size.width)];

    //----fix image orientation
    image  = [image fixSlotOrientation];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Then in my `AGIPCAssetsController.m`(Where the retaining of the image `checkmark` part)

```
- (void)loadAssets
{
    count = 0;
  [self.assets removeAllObjects];

    AGIPCAssetsController *blockSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        // Where I make an array to put the `ALAsset Url`
        selectedPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:blockSelf.imagePickerController.selection];

        @autoreleasepool {
            [blockSelf.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                // ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [result defaultRepresentation];
                // NSUInteger assetindex= [blockSelf.assetsGroup numberOfAssets];

                if (result == nil) 
                {
                    return;
                }



                AGIPCGridItem *gridItem = [[AGIPCGridItem alloc] initWithAsset:result andDelegate:blockSelf];
                if(count < blockSelf.imagePickerController.selection.count)
                {
                    if ( blockSelf.imagePickerController.selection != nil && 
                        [result isEqual:[selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:count]])
                    {
                        gridItem.selected = YES;
                        count++;
                        NSLog(@" %@",result);
                    }
                }
                [blockSelf.assets addObject:gridItem];

            }];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [blockSelf reloadData];

        });

    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think cause both of them have the same variable reference ,
check your variable reference and compare between both and let me know what u found .

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea and not an exact solution. On Done button action, is it possible to save the image with name as some unique property of `rep`. Probably `[rep filename]` or `[rep url]` can be used as image name while saving in place of `@"oneSlotImages%u.png"`. And in `loadAssets` read all the images stored in cache and compare its file name against the file names of images in `selectedPhotos` and remove it from the `selectedPhotos` array if it is not present in cache.

Comment: I have other images in NSCaches. So I renamed them as `@"oneSlotImages%u.png"`

Comment: What exactly is info? Is it the array of all selectedPhotos?